# Missing authentication methods in IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

We installed IIS on two servers. On the first server we have access to all the authentication methods we need. But on the second server half of them are missing. We tried reinstalling IIS on the second server, but that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add these as roles to IIS.

-Go to your server manager (start->Administrative tools-> Server Manager)

-Expand Roles and Web Server (IIS)

-Scroll down to Role Services, and click Add Role Services on the right

-Enable all the types you need under the security section.

Comment: Does this require a Reboot?

Comment: There is no `Server Manager` in Administrative tools in Win 10

Comment: I didn't need a reboot, but I did have to restart Computer Management for the new options to be visible.

Answer (score 20):

Here's how to do it:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to Programs and Features
3. Click 'Turn Windows features on or off'
4. Scroll down to `Internet Information Services` and expand it
5. Expand `World Wide Web Services`
6. Expand `Security`
7. Check off whichever Auth methods you need.

Comment: This is a valid procedure for IIS on the desktop (e.g. Windows 7). For Windows Server variants, use accepted answer above.

Comment: **ADDITION:** you also must add `World Wide Web Services - Application Development Features - ASP.NET x.x` Otherwise Forms Auth will still not show up